# How to remove extra space between two tables in latex

Tags: latex

I wanted to remove extra space between the two tables.

```
\begin{table}[h]\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{9.9cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

between these two tables I am getting too much spaces. I wont to reduce the space and start the 2table after first with space of say 2cm.

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You could use a `\vspace{-2em}` for example between your tables.

Comment: This does not always work and it could potentially cause problems when table floats: words may lay on each other. If you have an almost ready version and only need to do some fine-tune. This is the way to go, otherwise, this is too ad-hoc and may be problematic when the text is changed.

Answer (score 17):

If you want the tables to always be consecutive, you should put them into the same table environment. If you have them in separate environments any sort of \vspace \vfill kludges may (will) not work if LaTeX typesets them on different pages.

```
\begin{table}[h]\small    
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{*adjust here*}
\begin{tabular}{|p{9.9cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a \vfill after the second table

```
\begin{table}[h]\small    
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{9.9cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vfill
```